# Can I call a static method of one class in another class under same package?

Tags: java, methods, static

Can call a method by class name in same package  without create object of class or without inheritance in java

```
public class BoxWeight /*extends Box*/{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /*BoxWeight myCat = new BoxWeight();*/
        /*Box myAnimal = myCat;*/
        Box.testClassMethod();<------------ why this possible 
        /* myAnimal.testInstanceMethod();*/
    }   
}

public class Box /*extends Bicycle*/{

    public static void testClassMethod() {
        System.out.println("The class" + " method in Box.");
    }
    public void testInstanceMethod() {
        System.out.println("The instance " + " method in Box.");
    }
}
```

my question is not this as you seems my qestion is this  "Can call a method by class name in same package without create object of class or without inheritance in java" but i have fix this i want to confirm is this possible or not

Comment: what exactly is your question?

Comment: Im not really sure what you're asking, but it seems you want to call a method on a class rather than an object, in which case im guessing you are talking about static methods?

Comment: my question is not this as you seems my qestion is this  "Can call a method by class name in same package without create object of class or without inheritance in java" but i have fix this i want to confirm is this possible or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call a method with the syntax `ClassName.methodName()` if the method is declared `static`, eg

```
class ClassName {
  static void methodName() {
    //...//
  }
}
```

More info about static class members can be found in the [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html).

Answer (score 0):

Make your method static then you can call that method by class name.

```
class A {
static void display(){

    System.out.println("Called..");
}
}
```

In same package you can call it as .

```
A.display();
```